# Select no SQL Server com indice

Tags: sql, query, select, servidor, índices

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um select no Sql Server de uma table que não possuí uma coluna de índice, porém neste select apresentar uma coluna de índice sequencial em ordem crescente.
Ex. 
Tabela: **Letras**

```
Coluna
D
E
S
```

E fazendo o select desta tabela, apresentar pra mim o resultado:

```
Indice Coluna
1        D
2        E
3        S
```

É possível? Pois preciso fazer uma importação de dados de um banco para outro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma solução, vou postar, talvez ajude mais alguém.

`Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) as Indice, Coluna from Letras`

No caso o row_number() precisa ter um over() que recebe um orderby obrigatório.
Como não queria ordenar por nenhuma coluna, mas pela ordem que foi inserido os dados na tabela, utilizei o order by GETDATE().